# Finding the geometric basis vectors of a tangent space in $\mathbb R^3$ given the abstract derivation definition of basis

Tags: differential-geometry

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Basis_of_the_tangent_space_at_a_point), I understand for a $C^\infty$ manifold $M$, if a chart $\varphi = (x^1, \ldots, x^n): U \to \mathbb R^n$ is given with $p \in U$, then one can define an ordered basis $\left\{\left.{\frac {\partial }{\partial x^{1}}}\right|_{p},\dots ,\left.{\frac {\partial }{\partial x^{n}}}\right|_{p}\right\}$ of $T_pM$ by

$$\forall i\in \{1,\ldots ,n\},~\forall f\in {C^{\infty }}(M):\qquad {\left.{\frac {\partial }{\partial x^{i}}}\right|_{p}}(f):=\left({\frac {\partial }{\partial x^{i}}}{\Big (}f\circ \varphi ^{-1}{\Big )}\right){\Big (}\varphi (p){\Big )}$$

I'm trying to tackle a concrete problem using this abstract definition. I'm given the parameterization $(x, y, \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$ of the northern hemisphere of a sphere $S^2$ embedded in $\mathbb R^3$. Using the above definition of the basis vectors, how do I calculate the geometric basis vectors of the tangent space at any arbitrary point $p = (a, b, c)$ in the northern hemisphere of $S^2$?

I think the parameterization $(x, y, \sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$ is basically the inverse of the coordinate chart $\varphi: S^2 \to \mathbb R^2$, but I don't see an $f$ anywhere? I'm confused because $f$ is supposed to be an *arbitrary* smooth function.

Comment: You don't see that $f$ because the definition of the abstract basis vector $\partial/\partial x_i$ says $\forall f$. In other words: $f$ is just a [test function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4401850/949989). The simplest way to understand abstract and concrete basis vectors is via tangents to curves in the manifold. See my link.